# Run Gradle-built App Continuously (as server daemon) even after logoff

Tags: kotlin, gradle, server

Gradle noob here.  I am running a Kotlin application server-side (Ubuntu 20.04), built with Gradle.  I can run it fine using:

```
sudo sh gradlew run
```

And even:

```
sudo sh gradlew run &
```

But as soon as I log out of the server, the app stops.

1. How do I keep the app running as a server daemon continuously?
2. How can I start it back up automatically after the server boots?

I can probably hack something together with bash scripts, but I want to know what the industry standard way of doing this is.

Comment: gradle is only a build tool and `run` should not be used for 'runtime'. Better to create a shell script for starting the application.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a task called `run`, I assume you have applied the [Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), which automatically also applies the [Distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html). This makes it possible to build a distribution of your application.

Type `gradlew installDist` to assemble an uncompressed distribution into `$buildDir/install/${project.name}`. You can also use the task `distZip` and `distTar` to package it.

In the distribution, there is a shell script in the `bin` folder to start the application with the correct classpath. From here, you need to add it to systemd as a normal service. See blogs like [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-java-jar-application-with-systemd-on-linux/) if you need help for that (but use the generated shell script instead of a raw `java` command for the service).